# Почему background-size не работает?

Tags: css3

Вроде все правильно(раньше всегда без проблем работал). Какие могут быть причины?

```css
.header
 background-size: cover
 background-image: url(../img/header/header.png) 
 padding-top: 182px
 padding-bottom: 76px
 text-align: center
 color: #fff
```

```html
<header class="header">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xl-12">
    <h1 class="header__title">  </h1>
    <p class="header__text"> </p>
    <button class="button button_empty"> </button>
    <button class="button button_full"> </button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

**Должна отображаться так**
[image: Должна отображаться так]

**А отображается вот так**
[image: А отображается вот так]

Comment: Ну как минимум css-код абсолютно некорректен синтаксически, почитайте любой учебник по css

Comment: В консоли показывается что вроде все свойства применялись.

Comment: Значит вы явно что-то не договариваете, потому что ваш код в текущем его виде ничего никуда не может применить по причине синтаксической некорректности

Comment: `background-image: url(../img/header/header.png)`  На всякий случай содержимое url я написала с двойными с одинарными кавычками все равно ничего не изменилось(правильный синтаксис с кавычками, то что здесь это после проверки без кавычек то есть тот вариант копипейтснула сюда).

Comment: Если конечно вы эту синтаксическую некорректность имели ввиду

Comment: У background-image правильный синтаксис любой, но у вас и без этого ещё 7 синтаксических ошибок в css-коде

Comment: точку запятую если имеете ввиду, то это фрагмент из sass файла

Comment: Ну то есть это вообще не css? Ну вот, не договаривали всё-таки

Comment: Нет. Здесь нет синтаксической ошибки. Если было бы gulp предупреждал бы меня

Comment: Взял ваш sass, подставил рабочую ссылку на картинку — `cover` замечательно работает, проблемы не существует https://jsfiddle.net/d4jgmz75/

Comment: У меня фон полностью не отображается, это может быть из-за размера(1400х779) картинки? Высота(нижняя часть) не отображается

Comment: Может у вас ссылка на картинку нерабочая?

Comment: Как она может быть нерабочим если фон отображается( просто не полностью)

Comment: «полностью не отображается» и «отображается не полностью» это разные вещи. Ну да ладно, что такое «Высота(нижняя часть)»? Непонятно, каково ожидаемое поведение и чем оно отличается от фактического. Уточните вопрос, дополните его скриншотами и составьте полноценный пример с настоящей картинкой, на котором будет наглядно видна проблема

Comment: Я и собираюсь вставить скриншот

Comment: @andreymal Вставила скриншоты

Comment: Вижу на скриншоте правильное поведение, картинка в соответствии с `cover` вписалась в элемент как сумела, и невлезающее было обрезано, как и должно быть. В чём проблема, по-прежнему непонятно

Comment: А как сделать чтобы она как на первом отображалась?  В bakground size проверяла применив все значения. Background-repeat тоже проверила. Проблема с height. Как у image height cделать 100%, хотя background-size: 100% это и делает

Comment: Очевидно, сделать высоту header достаточной для влезания в него картинки. Сейчас у header вообще никакая высота не задана

Comment: Наглядно https://jsfiddle.net/hcd51y43/

Comment: Помогли, спасибо большое. и плюс надо задать background-repeat: no-repeat задать, а то повторяется фон, когда чуть больше задаю height

Comment: Сурово, да, тогда смысла в чат переносить нет, раз у вас доступа нету. Тогда восстановлю и удалю эти. А вам рекомендую на Мете [вопрос задать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) по поводу чата, чтоб решить проблему.

Comment: Спасибо что вернули. Как времени будет задам этот вопрос